# Magento2 CSS Rule Overriding

Tags: magento2, less, response

At 300px the page body has 0.3 opacity. For some reason, regardless of the order of these rules in the less file - they are always outputted into the file in the wrong order. Am I being stupid? Is this just me?

```
.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'max') and (@break = @screen__xs) {
    body {
        opacity: 0.7;
    }
}

.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'max') and (@break = @screen__s) {
    body {
        opacity: 0.3;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My implementation was very badly mistaken. I now believe that the function of media-width is to group media queries (written the standard way/less method).

I could still be wrong, but I am not having conflicting rules now.